# Open for Files Only on POSIX

Tags: c, posix

It is well known that in C calling `open()` will return a file descriptor, given a `pathname` and optional `flags`.

```
int fd;
if ((fd = open(pathname, O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
    printf("Could not open file\n");
    return;
}
```

In the [man page for `open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), a flag `O_DIRECTORY` is defined where:

> If pathname is not a directory, cause the open to fail.  This
>     flag was added in kernel version 2.1.126, to avoid denial-of-
>     service problems if opendir(3) is called on a FIFO or tape
>     device.

But I couldn't seem to find something like `O_FILE`, which would cause `open()` to fail on directories, rather than files.

Is there such a flag that can be passed to `open()` or another way of determining if `pathname` is a file, rather than calling `stat()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such flag.  The `stat` function is unacceptable as well because it has a race condition.  (In general, you should only call `stat` by itself, not in combination with `open`.)

Your options are:

1. Use `fstat`.
2. Open the file for writing, which returns `EISDIR` for directories.
3. Call `read`, which returns `EISDIR` for directories.